# ¿Cómo llamar a un método de otro controlador en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando llamar un método de otro *controller* pero cuando hago la instancia me devuelve todo vacío, ¿cuál es el método correcto para hacerlo?

esto es lo que hago:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\OtroController;

class MiControllerextends Controller
{

 public function metodoMiController(Request $request){

    $objeto = new OtroController();
    $objeto = new metodoOtroController($parametro);

 }

}
```

La respuesta que obtengo es vacía.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, sin embargo, llamar un método de otro controlador directamente es considerado una mala práctica y estás rompiendo varios principios de la programación orientada a objetos.

En general, si necesitas un método en más de un controlador, quiere decir que debes hacerlo reutilizable, por lo cual deberías utilizar herencia, o crear un trait e importarlo en los dos controladores, todo depende de la estructura de tu proyecto, incluso podrías hasta crear servicios, otras capas adicionales, etc.

---

En resumen, sugeriría que crees un trait y que lo utilices en ambos controladores:

```
class MiController extends Controller
{
    use MiTrait;

    // ...

 }
```

Comment: Quien haya votado negativo, por favor explique sus motivos, o genere una mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

La forma más fácil de hacerlo es esta:

```
public function metodoMiController(Request $request){

    app(OtroController:class)->metodoOtroController();
}
```

La mejor práctica es hacerlo con traits, metodología para la reutilización de código de php. Ejemplo trait:

```
trait EjemploTrait{

    public function metodoComun() {
     // .....
    }
}
```

Controllers:

```
class MiController extends Controller
{
    use EjemploTrait;
    public function metodoMiController(Request $request){

        $this->metodoComun();
    }
}
class OtroController extends Controller
{
    use EjemploTrait;
    public function metodoOtroController(){

        $this->metodoComun();
    }
}
```

Para ver dónde almacenarás el trait, puedes crear una carpeta `app/Traits`, y en ahí creas `EjemploTrait.php`.

Para más información sobre traits, puedes ver la documentación oficial
[aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php)

Answer (score 0):

No se si aun te sirva. lo que tienes que hacer es esto

```
    use App\Http\Controllers\OtroController;

class MiControllerextends Controller
{

 public function metodoMiController(Request $request){

    $objeto = new OtroController();
    $myVariable = $objeto->elMetodoDelOtroControlador();

 }

}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], ¿podrías explicar como este código soluciona el problema?

Comment: Además ¿por qué directamente una instancia de un controlador dentro de otro?, ¿en todo caso no habría sido mas simple una clase en una capa por separado e inyectarla en el método?